# AnyTime Picker pops up behind the dialog box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm using the AnyTime Picker (http://www.ama3.com/anytime/) within a JQuery UI Dialog box.
The thing is, that the time picker always pops up behind the dialog box.
Any ideas how to get it to pop up in front of the dialog?

Regards,
JAClerigo

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add this to your css file:

```
div.AnyTime-win {z-index:9999}
```

Comment: It Works! But you must remove the first dot in .div

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry for that, I was thinking on something else :)

Comment: There needs to be something about this in the doco. An awesome control, that's for sure though - I've ditched the JQuery UI one forever!

Comment: The z-index value should be greater than dialog box's z-index value. I came across a scenario where my dialog box's z-index was 10000, so in that case I need to put a value greater than 10000 to show my Anytime picker on top of dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

lonut is correct.  The CSS Z-Index property defines the stack order of an element.  Therefore an element with a z-index greater than another element will be displayed on top.  Setting the value to 9999 should bring it to the front.